# Buscar apenas campos do formulário com valor diferente de 0 e colocar na variável PHP

Tags: php, formulário, variáveis, post, input

Tenho um formulário de orçamento com 70 produtos em que o usuario escolhe a quantidade de produtos que ele quer de cada um.

Todos estão nomeados com id p1, p2...p70 e são inputs de tipo numero.

```
<form method="post">
<input type="number" value="0" name="p1" id="p1">
<input type="number" value="0" name="p2" id="p2">
...
<input type="number" value="0" name="p70" id="p70">
</form>
```

Preciso de uma função PHP que insira apenas os itens que forem diferentes de 0 (que é o valor padrão) em uma variável para montar um tabela que será exportada para excel.

O que tenho é o seguinte:

```
// Monta o cabeçalho da tabela    
$data = '<table><tbody><tr><td>CABEÇALHO</td></tr>';

// Traz cada linha que o valor é diferente de 0
if($_POST['form']['p1'] != '0'){
    $data .= '<tr><td>'.$_POST["form"]["p1"].'</td></tr>';
}
if($_POST['form']['p2'] != '0'){
    $data .= '<tr><td>'.$_POST["form"]["p2"].'</td></tr>';
}

// Coloca o rodapé e fecha a tabela
$data .= '<tr><td>RODAPÉ</td></tr></tbody></table>';
```

O problema desse que fiz é que teria que ter 70 ifs, acredito que deva existir uma forma mais simples, mas não sei qual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faz um loop de 1 a 70 criando as linhas em que o valor do `$_POST` seja diferente de 0:

```
    <?php
$data = '<table><tbody><tr><td>CABEÇALHO</td></tr>';

for($x=1;$x<=70;$x++){
  if($_POST['form']['p'.$x] != '0'){
   $data .= '<tr><td>'.$_POST['form']['p'.$x].'</td></tr>';
  }
}

$data .= '<tr><td>RODAPÉ</td></tr></tbody</table>';
    ?>
```

Comment: funcinoou, valeu!

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php 
cabeçalho...

foreach($_POST['form'] as $value){
   $table .= ($value) ? '<tr><td>'.$value.'</td></tr>'; : '';
}

footer...
```

Se houver alterações na quantidade de itens, o código ainda tem de funcionar.